# Derivative of a Heaviside function?

Tags: calculus

If I have the following function:

$\ y(x) = Ax + \frac{1}{2}Bx^2 + W U(x-\frac{1}{2}) $

where A,B,W are constants, and U(x - x0) is the Heaviside function.

What would its derivative be?

$\frac{dy}{dx} = A + Bx + W(??) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of the Heaviside step function isn't an ordinary function. It is a generalised function called the dirac delta function.

The delta function has the following properties,

$$ \delta(x) = \begin{cases} \infty \qquad x=0 \\ 0 \qquad x\neq0\end{cases}$$

$$ \int_a^b \delta(x) f(x) = f(0) \qquad (a < 0 < b)$$

From this we can see that,

$$ \int_{-1}^x \delta(x) dx = U(x)$$

Comment: so its derivative would b $\ \delta(x) $ or $\ \delta(x-\frac{1}{2}) $  ?

Comment: The second one.